# Change font size of list item when it's active

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar list and when one of the list items is active I would like it to be double the size of the others, making it clear that is the page you are on. However, my current code only makes it bigger during the mouse click, not while you're on the page as I would like.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.sellingmethodnav {
  background-color: #3F51B5;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.sellingmethodnav li {
  display: inline;
}

.sellingmethodnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

.sellingmethodnav li:active {
  font-size: 200%;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="sellingmethodnav">
  <li><a href="./quoting_assistant.html" class="active">CPC</a></li>
  <li><a href="../CPM/quoting_assistant_CPM.html">CPM</a></li>
  <li><a href="../CPA/quoting_assistant_CPA.html">CPA</a></li>
  <li><a href="../CPI/quoting_assistant_CPI.html">CPI</a></li>
  <li><a href="../CPE/quoting_assistant_CPE.html">CPE</a></li>
  <li><a href="../CPV/quoting_assistant_CPV.html">CPV</a></li>
  <li><a href="../CPCV/quoting_assistant_CPCV.html">CPCV</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) is a pseudo-class that refers to when the element in question is being clicked on.

Comment: .active {
  font-size: 200%;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

Comment: make a new class 'active' and give the properties to it

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

HTML

```
<div class="sellingmethodnav">
 <li><a href="#" class="active">CPC</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">CPM</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">CPA</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">CPI</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">CPE</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">CPV</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">CPCV</a></li>
```

CSS

```
.sellingmethodnav a:active, .sellingmethodnav a:focus {
font-size: 200%;
color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tractionworks/nm934g5h/1/

Is that what you are going for?

Comment: This is it! Thank you